# Landsat Collection 2 surface reflectance harmonization

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat

I am using Landsat 5, 7, 8 collection 2 level 2 to extract NDVI time series with GEE.
Is it necessary to apply the Landsat ETM+ to OLI Harmonization with the Roy et al. (2016) coefficients to collection 2?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the consensus is no, based on an answer to a frequently asked question in google earth engine (GEE) documentation:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/faq#is_cross-sensor_landsat_surface_reflectance_harmonization_needed

> Roy et al., 2016 included an analysis of reflectance differences between Landsat 7-8 TOA and surface reflectance. They published the OLS and RMA coefficients so readers could transform the reflectance values of one sensor's data to another. The final line of the paper states: "Although sensor differences are quite small they may have significant impact depending on the Landsat data application." However, this analysis was based on pre-collection data.

> The improvements made during Collection 1 and Collection 2 reprocessing may influence the relationship between sensors, but as far as we know, there have been no analyses similar to Roy et al. (2016) for Collection 1 or Collection 2 data. Despite no formal analysis, there seems to be a general consensus among influential Landsat users that no correction is needed for Collection 2, Level 2 (surface reflectance) data. For example, in a reply to a question regarding the need for Collection 2, Level 2 harmonization, Mike Wulder of the Landsat Science Team noted that depending on the nature of the application of interest (including land cover mapping and change detection), the Collection 2 surface reflectance products are highly suitable and reliable, without need for cross-sensor adjustment.